# Website connected to Bitcoin RPC Wrapper on second server (Bitcoin Core) - Purchase fails

Tags: php, wrapper, rpc, bitcoin

I am trying to connect my ecommerce site to enable payments with Bitcoin. When I had the site and Bitcoin Core running on the same server, it worked fine. I now use a second server for the Bitcoin Core and orders are getting the error "Trying to access array offset on valie of type null".
Given it worked before, I assume it's the Bitcoin RPC problem.

Is there a problem with my config?

**PHP files on 95.XXX.XX.XXX (where the website is stored)**

**config PHP:**

```
/**
 * RPCWrapper settings
 *
 * Uses data from .environemntConfig file
 */
'bitcoin' => [
    'host' => environemntConfig('BITCOIN_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'username' => environemntConfig('BITCOIN_USERNAME', 'username'),
    'password' => environemntConfig('BITCOIN_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'port' => environemntConfig('BITCOIND_PORT', 18332),
],
```

**environmentConfig PHP:**

```
BITCOIN_HOST=65.xxx.xx.xxx
BITCOIN_PORT=8332
BITCOIN_USERNAME=MYUSERNAME
BITCOIN_PASSWORD=MYSTRONGPASSWORD!
```

**BITCOIN CORE CONFIG (running on second server: 65.xxx.xx.xxx):**

```
server=1 
testnet=0
rpcuser=MYUSERNAME
rpcpassword=MYSTRONGPASSWORD!
server=1
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcport=9337
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Show the response you are gtting when on the same server and then the one you are getting when on the other server.

Answer (score 1):

The error was that the rpc ports were not open on the Bitcoin running server.